# Twilio Trust Onboard SIM

Tags: arduino, twilio, x509certificate, sim-card

I am trying to connect my Arduino "MKR gsm 1400" with a Twilio Trust Onboard SIM card. To send data to my NodeJS server over HTTPs

If I connect to a regular HTTPs will the sim sign the request?
And I can then validate the request on the server?

Or do the Arduino have to extract the x509 and use that to later sign the request?

Comment: Did you get any documentation with the SIM kit?

Comment: No, I did not. Got it at Microsoft Build. I only have the documentation that I provided in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The limited documentation that is there says

https://www.twilio.com/docs/wireless/trust-onboard

> **Available Key** certificates will be on the SIM card but the text is freely available on the device. Your code will have access to the full text of the public and private keys and certificate. This is intended to be used with hardware that requires you to hand over this data for HTTPS communication. These live in a simple global platform applet that holds files with only read operations.
>
> **Signing Key** certificates will be inside the SIM card with no way to export the text contents. You will utilize TLS libraries such as mBed that can request the SIM card to sign requests using the keys and perform request encryption. This is intended for use cases where your hardware allows you to offload the TLS communication to the SIM card. These live in a global platform applet called mIAS that implements a full security suite (similar to OpenSSL).

So closely looking at the `Signing Key` description, for NodeJS you will have to sign the request yourself

Comment: So my device send a request to my server, then I sign the request with the ***"programmable-wireless.signing.bundle"*** and then the device uses that to connect to my server?

Comment: Honestly not very sure, as I couldn't find more information on the answer I posted.